# Apache log file delay?

Tags: apache-2.2

Does anybody know why Apache might be delaying writing to the all-activity log file? For instance the modified time on the file is 8:01:42 even though I just accessed the site at 13:29:00. If it is in fact delaying, where does it put the data in the meantime?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not delaying (I'm not sure there's any function which would give that), which means it's not writing to the log you think it is.  The other option is the clock on the server is wrong.

Comment: It was actually writing to a different file and what I was seeing was the archived copy.

Answer (score 5):

Apache may in fact be delaying writing logs. There is a buffer option for logging -- it's not the default behavior, but there is such an option, "[buffered logs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#bufferedlogs)".

Also, there will usually be normal, every-day buffering happening with writing to files. But you should see your latest log entries popping out after a few minutes (my general estimate) at most.

Finally, are you sure you're looking at the right log file? You should check the config to be sure it's logging where you think; or use your system's open files ("fuser" on most unix flavors) command to make sure a process has the log you're looking at open, and that the process is your web server.